# Xcode 5.1.1 not able to select new pre release version while submitting app to appstore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I have created a new pre-release version in iTunes connect for one of my app which is already there in app-store.

So the Live version is 2.1 and I have created a new version 2.2 in iTunes and it is showing as `2.2 Prepare for Submission`

with yellow icon besides it. Also I have changed my xcode 5.1.1  `version` and `code` strings to `2.2`

But when I archive my build and select submit to appstore via xcode 5.1.1 it is not giving me the option to select the new build version 2.2. It is showing the current app version `2.1` in `choose profile to sign with` screen.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong this time because earlier as soon as I created a new version it was visible in xcode.

Thanks

Comment: To Submit to the AppStore you will need at least Xcode 6 with the iOS 8.0 SDK.

Comment: Try with Application Loader.

Comment: Nope as far as I have read that upto 1 June you can submit app updates from xcode version 5.1.1 and it is showing in iTunes as well that I can submit with xcode 5.1.1

Comment: Leena while trying with application loader 3.0 it shows me the binary details but when I click next it start to upload. it does not give me the option to select build. Thanks

Comment: I went ahead with application loader 3.0 and the build was reflected in pre-release version. Strange this happening but anyways I got my build uploaded. Thanks everyone for their comments.

Answer (score 0):

First clean your project build and recheck **Version and Build** both before archiving your project.